# Ternary Operator throws error while @if works

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I was working on a blade, while i encountered an issue with my ternary operator throwing error

> syntax error, unexpected ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\drm\resources\views\includes\sidebar.blade.php) Unexpected "("

at

> `<li class="<?php echo e(preg_match("/project/i", url()->current()) ?
>   'active'); ?>">`

This doesn't work

```
<li class="{{ preg_match('/project/i', url()->current()) ? 'active' }}">
```

This works

```
<li class="@if(preg_match("/project/i", url()->current()))  {{'active'}} @endif">
```

This is a test case and `preg_match("/project/i", url()->current()` returns 1 or true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP there is two kinds of if operations we can write:

1. the first one and the known one is `@if/@endif`.

example1:

```
if( $valid ) {
    $x = 'yes';
} else {
    $x = 'no';
}
```

2. the second one is the short form known as `ternary operator ($valid)
       ? yes: no;`

this is example1 but with ternary operator:

```
$x = $valid ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

let's go back to your first use case that match to this :

```
<li class="{{ preg_match('/project/i', url()->current()) ? 'active' }}">
```

in this use case, you have a lexical structure issue because you did not respect the `ternary operator`, so PHP engine cannot resolve what you have written.

for more information about [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 2):

try adding else condition

```
<li class="{{ preg_match('/project/i', url()->current()) ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that without else ternary operator would throw error.

Answer (score 1):

you need use else

```
<li class="{{ (preg_match('/project/i', url()->current())) ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Comment: yeah, else was causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

try something like this by adding colon:   it evaluates 'active' if value of preg_match('/project/i', url()->current()) is true otherwise ''

```
<li class="{{ preg_match('/project/i', url()->current()) ? 'active':'' }}">
```

i edited it. hope this helps